# How can i get the first content of a python synsets list?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, synset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN3qc.png)I have a scrapped text stored under the variable "message".
I have removed the StopWords and stored the result with the variable "without_stop_words".
I want to loop through each words in the 'without_stop_words' and get their MEANINGS AND PRONOUNS.

Currently i am trying to get the MEANINGS but I'm getting an error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V55ve.png)

```
   
 for writeup in writeups:
        message = writeup.text
        #Stop Words
        stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        #print(stop_words)

        tokenized_words = word_tokenize(message)
        #Filtering Stop Words
        without_stop_words = []
        for word in tokenized_words:
            if word not in stop_words:
                without_stop_words.append(word)            
                #Word Meanings
        word_meanings = []
        for each_word in without_stop_words:
            sync_words = wordnet.synsets(each_word)
            meaning = sync_words[0].definition()
            print(meaning)
```

I want to get the MEANING of each word in the "without_stop_words".

Comment: Don't include code as a screenshot, put it as inline code, as you have also done. The same for error messages and program output wherever possible. (I was going to say make images inline when you use them, not links, but just discovered that is a limit when less than 10 rep!)   See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line

```
meaning = sync_words[0].definition()
```

And it indicates that `sync_words` is empty

```
for each_word in without_stop_words:
    sync_words = wordnet.synsets(each_word)
    if sync_words:
        meaning = sync_words[0].definition()
        word_meanings.append(meaning)
    else:
        # Whatever you want to do if it's empty
```

This will stop the error, but you should try to find out why `sync_words` is empty in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, It solved the error..... However, the printed result is not readable. Also, how can i trace the cause of the empty sync_words??

Comment: @Abuchi sure, i can help you further. The function you're using, `wordnet.synsets` returns a list with sets of possible synonyms to that word. The reason `sync_words` is empty is because there are no synonyms to one or more words in NLTK database. This could happen, for example, if your word is a proper name, like "Maria" or maybe a very recent slang. The `print(meaning)` result is not readable because it's just a bunch of dictionary definitions. What your code does is: Take each word from the page, look for a synonym, search for the dictionary definition of this synonym and then print it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you take a closer look at the [wordnet docs](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html). There you can understand exactly what each piece of your code does, since i imagine that's not what you intended to do. By the way, since the anwer solved the error, it's a good idea to mark it as the accepted answer, so people with the same error will find it as a duplicate to their questions and get their answer easily.

Comment: No, problem! Always a pleasure to help :)